# How to get the value of a column for a specific dataframe's row

Tags: python, dataframe

This is a dictionary that stores the prices of apartments for a specific district in Paris based on its size. I need the value of the 'Square Feet' column for each row of the dataframe.

```
app_sale_prices = {
    75001:np.random.randn(apartment_prices.get(75001) * df['Square Feet'], apartment_prices.get(75001) * df['Square Feet'] + apartment_prices.get(75001) * 0.1)}
```

But this gives me the error: TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
The error is probably because of df['Square Feet'].

The rest of the code:

```
apartment_prices = {
    75001:12811,
    75002:11623,
    75003:12345,
    75004:13197,
    75005:12335,
    75006:14420,
    75007:13899,
    75008:11676,
    75009:10932,
    75010:10301,
    75011:9244,
    75012:9146,
    75013:10032,
    75014:9951,
    75015:9350,
    75016:11079,
    75017:10687,
    75018:9664,
    75019:8385,
    75020:8744
}

app_sale_conditions = [
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75001),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75002),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75003),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75004),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75005),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75006),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75007),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75008),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75009),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75010),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75011),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75012),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75013),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75014),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75015),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75016),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75017),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75018),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75019),
    (df['Zipcode'] == 75020)
]

app_sale_choices = [
    app_sale_prices.get(75001), app_sale_prices.get(75002),app_sale_prices.get(75003),app_sale_prices.get(75004),
    app_sale_prices.get(75005),app_sale_prices.get(75006),app_sale_prices.get(75007),app_sale_prices.get(75008),
    app_sale_prices.get(75009),app_sale_prices.get(75010),app_sale_prices.get(75011),app_sale_prices.get(75012),
    app_sale_prices.get(75013),app_sale_prices.get(75014),app_sale_prices.get(75015),app_sale_prices.get(75016),
    app_sale_prices.get(75017),app_sale_prices.get(75018),app_sale_prices.get(75019),app_sale_prices.get(75020)
]

user_df["app_sale_price"] = np.select(app_sale_conditions, app_sale_choices)
print(user_df.head())
```

Comment: have you tried `df['Square Feet'].astype('int32')` ?

Comment: I get the same error